# mouseover event unable to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Im doing a mouseover function on my asp page. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".Menu1").mouseover(
            function () { $("td_1").show(); },
            function () { $("td_1").hide(); }
          );
            $(".Menu2").mouseover(
          function () { $("td_2").show(); },
          function () { $("td_2").hide(); }
          );
            $(".Menu3").mouseover(
            function () { $("td_3").show(); },
            function () { $("td_3").hide(); }
          );
            $(".Menu4").mouseover(
          function () { $("td_4").show(); },
          function () { $("td_4").hide(); }
          );
            $(".Menu5").mouseover(
          function () { $("td_5").show(); },
          function () { $("td_5").hide(); }
          );
            $(".Menu6").mouseover(
          function () { $("td_6").show(); },
          function () { $("td_6").hide(); }
          );
            $(".Menu7").mouseover(
          function () { $("td_7").show(); },
          function () { $("td_7").hide(); }
          );
            $(".Menu8").mouseover(
          function () { $("td_8").show(); },
          function () { $("td_8").hide(); }
          );
        })
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
<table width="963" height="70" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:99px">
              <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" BackColor="Purple" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">                  
                  <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="index.aspx" Text="Hello1">                              
                            </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>
            </td>
            <td style="width:112px">
              <asp:Menu ID="Menu2" BackColor="Yellow"  Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">
                  <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="open-live-account.aspx" Text="Hello2">
                            </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>
            </td>
             <td style="width:117px">
              <asp:Menu ID="Menu3" BackColor="Red" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">
                  <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="education-center.aspx" Text="Hello3">
                            </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>

            </td>
            <td style="width:121px">
              <asp:Menu ID="Menu4" BackColor="Black" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">
                  <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="investment-news.aspx" Text="Hello4">
                            </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>

            </td>
              <td>

            <asp:Menu ID="Menu5" BackColor="Blue" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">

                  <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="affiliate-program.aspx" Text="Hello5">
                            </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>

            </td>
            <td>
             <asp:Menu ID="Menu6"  BackColor="Green" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">

                  <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="support.aspx" Text="Hello6">
                            </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>

            </td>
             <td style="width:118px">
             <asp:Menu ID="Menu7" BackColor="Pink" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">

                  <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="about-us.aspx" Text="Hello7">
                            </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>
            </td>
             <td style="width:140px">
             <asp:Menu ID="Menu8"  BackColor="Orange" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">
              <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="contact-us.aspx" Text="Hello8">
                 </asp:MenuItem>                          
                  </Items>
                  </asp:Menu>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <table>
    <tr>
      <td><table width="963" height="15" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:none">
        <tr>
          <td id="td_1" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101">
          <a href="open-live-account.aspx" class="style101">Open Live Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/File/nzf4setup.exe" class="style101">Download</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/deposit.aspx" class="style101">Deposit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/withdraw.aspx" class="style101">Withdrawal</a>
              </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_2" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25">
                                <div align="center" class="style101">
                                    <a href="open-live-account.aspx" class="style101">Open Live Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="deposit.html" class="style101">Deposit</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html"
                                        class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="withdraw.html" class="style101">Withdraw</a><a
                                            href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="trading-platform.html"
                                                class="style101">Trading Platform</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="market-hours.html" class="style101">Market Hours</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html"
                                        class="style101"></a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="trading-services.html" class="style101">Trading Services</a><a
                                        href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div>
            </td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_3" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="education-center.html" class="style101">Education Center</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="risk-assessment.html" class="style101">Risk Assessment</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="risk-warning.html" class="style101">Risk Warning</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="money-management-responsible-trading.html" class="style101">Money Management &amp; Responsiblity Trading</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_4" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="investment-news.html" class="style101">Investment news</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="economic-calendar.html" class="style101">Economic Calendar</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_5" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="affiliate-program.html" class="style101">Affiliate Program</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="white-label.html" class="style101">White Label</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_6" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="contact-us.aspx" class="style101">Contact Us</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="nzf-faq.html" class="style101">FAQ</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="site-map.html" class="style101">SiteMap</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_7" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="about-us.html" class="style101">About Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="nzf-vision.html" class="style101">NZF Vision</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="careers.html" class="style101">Careers</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_8" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="contact-us.aspx" class="style101">Contact Us</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="nzf-faq.html" class="style101">FAQ</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="site-map.html" class="style101">SiteMap</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          </tr>
    </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Somehow, when i try to mouseover, it does not response to me. May i know what did i did wrong? I try to check for any error using debugging tools but so far no error was display on the tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `jQuery` you are targetting by class (e.g. `$(".Menu1").mouseover`), but inside your `ASP` you've given them ID's (`Menu ID="Menu1"`) instead.

- Firstly, try changing them both to the same type (both class or both ID).
- Secondly, you are targetting td_1 etc. inside your jQuery, but without using an ID/Class selector, so it's never going to work.

For example, your first section could resemble the following:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#Menu1").hover(
  function () { $("#td_1").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_1").hide(); }
);
```

**ASP:**

```
<td style="width:99px">
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" BackColor="Purple" Orientation="Horizontal"  ForeColor="White" runat="server" CssClass="Menu" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false">                  
  <Items>
   <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="index.aspx" Text="Hello1">                              
   </asp:MenuItem>                          
  </Items>
 </asp:Menu>
</td>
```

Comment: @NgYangYang Of course it won't, there is no such thing as td_1 etc. Read my updated answer :)

Comment: Actually, it exist. What I'm trying to do is the id="td_1" is in another table below. The asp:menu is on a table on top and I wanted to hide a row at the table below while the mouseover event is on another table. Check back my code and you will understand what i means.

Comment: @NgYangYang In that case, just use the jQuery I put.

Comment: @NgYangYang Have you got an online example I can try? Just try with one example, target it by ID, make sure you're using exactly the same ID, and it'll work

Comment: i try  with a much shorted and simple version but still not working.

Comment: @NgYangYang ASP doesn't work in jsFiddle remember. Check out my jsFiddle, that's the basics

Comment: @NgYangYang Did you check my comment? ASP doesn't work in jsFiddle at all, so nothing will show up. It only works for HTML, JS and CSS

Comment: @NgYangYang I've got it working - http://jsfiddle.net/6ejwh/2/ - don't forget to tick my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you need an id selector `#` there instead of class `.`

```
  $("#Menu1").mouseover(
  //-^-- here
```

and i think what you need here is `hover()` cause hover has to callback function for mouseenter and mouseleave

```
$("#Menu1").hover(
        function () { $("#td_1").show(); },
                   //----^^--here
        function () { $("#td_1").hide(); }
                   //----^^--here
      );
```

note: you need a seletor in `td_1` either class or id..and i couldn't find any element with these name

Comment: All the elements are there just that it is in different table

Comment: U mean change it to .hover and # instead? Nope not working I assure you

Answer (score 0):

You are using Class instead of ID

AND your Jquery should look like:

```
  $("#Menu1").mouseenter(function() {
     $("td_1").show();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
     $("td_1").hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access these tags: `td_1` etc. as they do not exist.
try `$('#td_1')...` instead. And don't forget to give the items the ID's `td_{num}`

**Edit**

Or use `$('td:nth-child({num})')`
And `$('#Menu1')` as you are giving them ID's ant not classes